# how do I wait for process to complete

Tags: java

I am a c++ engineer so please be gentle!!
I have some Java code that starts a process, but I want to do is halt execution until the new process completes.

How do I do this in Java?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement wait between processes in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654525/implement-wait-between-processes-in-java)

Comment: how are you starting a process from Java?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object that represents the newly created process use [`Process.waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29), which:

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.

A `Process` object can be obtained from:

- [`ProcessBuilder.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29)
- [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) (of which there are several overloads).

Answer (score 2):

If a "process" is a `java.lang.Process` obtained by `java.lang.Runtime`, then use `Process.waitFor()`

Just for the sake of completeness: normally in Java, you work with threads, and the option to wait for a thread is to call `thread.join()`

Answer (score 0):

`Read the stream from Process`. It will wait for process completion before executing remaining code.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command(process)", null, new File("path of process where to execute"));
    InputStream is=p.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
      line = reader.readLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you are trying to synchronize processes (Threads).

If for example, you want to wait for completion of your thread t1 before resuming your main process here is an idea:

```
Thread t1 = new MyThreadExample();
t1.start();
t1.join(); //wait for completion
/*
  write what you want to do after completion

*/
```